# Where should I put reuse_actors=True?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, hyperparameters, ray, gridsearchcv

After running the below code, it says

> INFO trainable.py:172 – Trainable.setup took 2940.989 seconds. if your trainable is slow to initialize, consider setting reuse_actors=True to reduce actor creation overheads

```
import ray
ray.init(address="auto", _temp_dir='/home/ray_dir')

rnd = random.seed(8)
grid_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3,random_state=rnd, shuffle=True)

from xgboost.callback import EarlyStopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(rounds = 50, maximize=True, save_best=True)
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(
                tree_method='gpu_hist',
                max_bin=512, 
                learning_rate = 0.0001,
                n_estimators=1000,
                objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0.01,
                scale_pos_weight = pos_weight, eval_metric= 'aucpr',
                callbacks=[early_stopping],
                verbosity = 0,
                nthread = 96
                )


param = {
    'eta': [0.01, 0.1, 0.3],
    'min_child_weight': [1,3,8,16],
    'max_depth':[25,50,100,500],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.4,0.6,0.8],
    'subsample': [0.4,0.6,0.8],
    'gamma':[0,0.5,2,10],
}

gs = TuneGridSearchCV (estimator=clf, param_grid=param,  cv=grid_cv, n_jobs = -1, refit=True, return_train_score = True, verbose=3, scoring = 'average_precision', use_gpu = True )

gs.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set= eval_set_xgboost, verbose=True)
```

Where should I add `reuse_actors=True` here in my code?

Comment: There's some discussion on that topic [here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/13475); does that help?

Comment: Their use case is different. The discussion is for tune.run(). But here, I am trying to use TuneGridSearchCV. I did not find any args. to pass this value (reuse_actors=True).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it always has `reuse_actors=True`.
TuneGridSearchCV does not have this degree of freedom.
You can see that in the [source code](https://github.com/ray-project/tune-sklearn/blob/ff4e5f69570836e043bc89e4812d5fea3361a1e0/tune_sklearn/tune_gridsearch.py#L280).

Comment: But, when I am running the code with TuneGridSearchCV, it asks me to consider it.

Comment: Is your trainable slow to initialize?

Comment: yes. it is slow @Bur